# Multiple detail rows and page breaks on report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, rdlc

I have a problem with a `rdlc` page breaking and table with multiple detail rows. Tried everything that crossed my mind, none works.

As you can see on the picture below, the table has 7 detail rows.
Now, when report is rendered, the page gets spitted between, for example, rows 2 and 3 which is bad.

**I wish to keep all of detail rows (that belong to one record) on the same page. How can I accomplish this?**

[image: Table illustration]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a group based on whatever joins the one record together, let's call it PlaceID.  So right click, Add Group, choose what to group by.

Then, under the row groups you should have a group by PlaceID, and underneath that, a row marked "Details".  Highlight Details in the lower section, which should highlight in the report the rows involved. Set the KeepTogether property of that section to True, should keep details on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the Group option mentioned by Jerry, this option in the Table Properties may help...

[image: Table Properties popup with "Keep together on one page if possible" option checked]